# Javascript removing accents

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer-7, diacritics

I want to use Evan Elliott's code (below) to remove accents in strings but its returns an "a" instead of the respective vanilla version of each character. I declare `<meta charset="utf-8">` at the top of my page.

```
function NormalizeString(s){
            var r=s.toLowerCase();
                        var r=s.toLowerCase();
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("\\s", 'g'),"");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[àáâãäå]", 'g'),"a");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("æ", 'g'),"ae");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("ç", 'g'),"c");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[èéêë]", 'g'),"e");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[ìíîï]", 'g'),"i");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("ñ", 'g'),"n");                            
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[òóôõö]", 'g'),"o");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("œ", 'g'),"oe");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[ùúûü]", 'g'),"u");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[ýÿ]", 'g'),"y");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("\\W", 'g'),"");
                        return r;  
  }
```

[EDIT]
Ok I made a test page to try to find out what the problem is:

```
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    function NormalizeString(s){
            var r=s.toLowerCase();
                        var r=s.toLowerCase();
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("\\s", 'g'),"");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[àáâãäå]", 'g'),"a");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("æ", 'g'),"ae");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("ç", 'g'),"c");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[èéêë]", 'g'),"e");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[ìíîï]", 'g'),"i");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("ñ", 'g'),"n");                            
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[òóôõö]", 'g'),"o");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("œ", 'g'),"oe");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[ùúûü]", 'g'),"u");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("[ýÿ]", 'g'),"y");
                        r = r.replace(new RegExp("\\W", 'g'),"");
                        return r;  
  }

    function loadhandler(){
       alert(NormalizeString('Opérations'))
    }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body class="" onload="loadhandler()">


    </body>

</html>
```

Still the output for "Opération" is "oparation". Is it because of my IE7 settings?

[EDIT]

"Opération" outputs "oparation" in Firefox too :(

Comment: Post your test case. This code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/W7pTu/

Comment: please provide an example, this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUqq7/) works. Of course the function will not work for characters other than the ones inside the regexps.

Answer (score 0):

This function may be useful for what you need:

```
function removeAccents (text) {
    var accents    = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž',
        accentsOut = "AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeeCcDIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuNnSsYyyZz",
        textNoAccents = [];

    for (var i in text) { 
        var idx = accents.indexOf(text[i]);
        if (idx != -1)
            textNoAccents[i] = accentsOut.substr(idx, 1);
        else
            textNoAccents[i] = text[i];
    }

    return textNoAccents.join('');
}
```