# Javascript replace diacritic characters in iso-8859-1

Tags: javascript, diacritics, iso-8859-1

I'm trying to replace some diacritics (accent) caracters in plain **javascript**. but I have no clue on what to do. My problem is that we use the charset **iso-8859-1**. If we'd use the utf-8, it would have been easier. I'm trying to make someting like [this script here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186302/javascript-removing-accents) (that works in UTF-8 encoding).

Can anyone help me on this one ? If I could just have the syntax for a **replace from "é" to "e"** I'd do the rest just fine. I tried some things with \xE9 but not beeing very familiar with regular expressions, I couldn't make it work.

Comment: What exactly do you ask about? The unicode escape sequences should work. Or does the code from the other question not work?

Comment: As I wrote, we use the charset iso-8859-1 and it doesn't work. Even a simple .replace("é", "e") doesn't work.

Comment: Then use `.replace("\u00E9", "e")` if you've got a different encoding. Or even better change to UTF-8, which is quasi-standard.

Comment: I'd be more than happy to change to UTF-8 but I unfortunately don't have the time to do so. My contract here is only for a few weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found this regex syntax :

```
        Recherche = Recherche.replace(/À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å/g, "A")
                             .replace(/à|á|â|ã|ä|å/g, "a")
                             .replace(/Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Õ|Ö|Ø/g, "O")
                             .replace(/ò|ó|ô|õ|ö|ø/g, "o")
                             .replace(/È|É|Ê|Ë/g, "E")
                             .replace(/è|é|ê|ë/g, "e")
                             .replace(/Ç|ç/g, "c")
                             .replace(/Ì|Í|Î|Ï/g, "I")
                             .replace(/ì|í|î|ï/g, "i")
                             .replace(/Ù|Ú|Û|Ü/g, "U")
                             .replace(/ù|ú|û|ü/g, "u");
```

Comment: You can replace `Recherche = Recherche.replace(...); Recherche = Recherche.replace(...)` by `Recherche = Recherche.replace(...).replace(...)`, shorten the code, and prevent a lot of cycle (don t need to copy the value back to Recherche and read it again each time).