# JS - Convert Special Tilde Characters etc?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to convert characters like ñ, á, é etc to normal English/Latin characters?

ñ should return n
á should return a
é should return e
etc

Comment: Did you try searching for a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34792866/4437888

Comment: @Matey sorry didnt know exactly what to search.

Comment: I feel like this thread provides a great (and simple to follow) solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286921/efficiently-replace-all-accented-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Use replace and Regex

```js
var str = "ñ á é ";
undefined
var res = str.replace("ñ", "n").replace("á", "a").replace("é", "e");
undefined
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with replace method.
for example

```js
var string = "Buenos días.";

var new_string = string.replace('í', 'i');

console.log(new_string)
```

if you want to add more character you can add another .replace method in end of new_string.